# How do I install openlierox on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I downloaded the deb package from  http://www.openlierox.net, and tried to install it using this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i openlierox_0.58.rc3_amd64.deb
```

but it didn't meet all requirements:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openlierox:
 openlierox depends on libgd2-xpm (>= 2.0.33); however:
  Package libgd2-xpm is not installed.
 openlierox depends on libgd2-xpm (>= 2.0.33) | libgd2-noxpm (>= 2.0.33);  however:
  Package libgd2-xpm is not installed.
  Package libgd2-noxpm is not installed.
```

I installed package `libgd-dev` as I thought it would solve the problem, which it didn't, so I tried ignoring it and install it by using this command:

```
sudo dpkg --ignore-depends=libgd2-xpm -i openlierox_0.58.rc3_amd64.deb
```

But there is problem when I try to run it, as I get this error:

```
openlierox: error while loading shared libraries: libgd.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I think it should be easy to fix by installing the `libgd2-xpm` package, but I didn't find it in a repository. What should I do, how do I properly install it?

Comment: `libgd2-xpm` http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgd2/libgd2-xpm_2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-6.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ... Install the package: `sudo gdebi Downloads/libgd2-xpm_2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-6.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb` . Note : The current version is "libgd3*".

Comment: You should check especially the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/769542/250300 from the possible duplicate target.

Answer (score 0):

In RHEL, `yum` and `rpm` have a similar relationship to `apt` and `dpkg`.  `yum` is the package manager that can look up packages from the repo, like `apt`, and `rpm` is like `dpkg`.

I mention this because `yum` has a `localinstall` option that installs all of the dependencies using repositories, and then installs the local `.rpm` file.

While `apt` does not have this functionality, `dpkg` will trigger those dependencies as needed, which means that `apt` becomes aware they are needed.

After you run your `dpkg -i` command, you can ask `apt` to fix the dependencies for you, and then try the install again:

```
apt-get install -f
dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb
```

Comment: APT does have the mentioned feature, it’s not well documented though. https://askubuntu.com/a/769542/250300